# Is Kaoru the first person who had sex with Ritsuko?

Tags: sakamichi-no-apollon

I just finished watching its anime, got curious about its ending, and found out by searching that the last 2 volumes are cramped in the last episode (so they skipped some scene).

I got to know that Ritsuko got a boyfriend when Kaoru was in Tokyo, so Kaoru breaks all his ties with Ritsuko. So I'm wondering if the manga stated if Ritsuko has sex with her boyfriend, because in the anime when Kaoru try to have sex with Ritsuko, she refuses (and that's when Kaoru starts ignoring her).

Is Kaoru the first person who had sex with Ritsuko? Is it ever answered in the manga?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate [What was omitted/skipped from the end of sakamichi no apollon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/what-was-omitted-skipped-from-the-end-of-sakamichi-no-apollon?rq=1)